# How to position a header in CSS to make it more responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to turn this design into a website using CSS. There is a problem that about positioning header "Mountains at night". I tried to use position:absolute and it's kind of working but it's not really responsive when I resize my window so is there any other way to achieve this?

[image]

Here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Background -->
<div class="bg">
        <!-- Menu -->
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="">about</a>
            <a href="">products</a>
            <a href="">team</a>
        </div>
            <h1 id="header">Mountains at night</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a CSS code:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Background image*/
.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("header.jpg");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Menu */

.menu{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-left:38%;
    word-spacing: 70px;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:12%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #header{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 40%;
  }

  .menu{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-left:25%;
    word-spacing: 30px;
}
```

I tried to use media query to make it look better on small screen but it still looks weird.

Comment: What you have tired so far?

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Sure, I just did.

Comment: Please include a working code snippet instead.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Jorjill/pen/poJoBXz

Answer (score 1):

Use a css grid system like bootstrap. After you read a little through the docs you will find yourself writing something like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <h1 id="header">Header</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```